# Drools Rule Template Error

Tags: drools

I am trying to run a program to generate DRL file from DROOLS template. I am using DRROSL 5.2.3 library jar. But it always gives an error saying "value import x.y.dto is not a valid column definition "

Below is my drools template file -

```
template header
abc

import x.y.dto;

template "dtoTemplate"

rule "dtoTemplate_0"

dialect "mvel"

when

    dto:dtoTemplate(abc == @{abc})
then 

    System.out.println ("Condition passed")
end

end template
```

Even if i remove the import statements it will give me an error on line saying 
rule "dtoTemplate_0" is not a valid colunm definition.

Please suggest.

Comment: As far as I remember, the `package` statement is mandatory in Drools. Try adding `package com.your.rules;` before the `import` statement.

Comment: yeah thanks for your response. It worked after adding package statement.